# Is there any cache option in Sweave [R]?

Tags: r, caching, sweave

Why `Sweave` is so poor?
Is there any cache option for chunk that enables caching as it is solved in `knitr` package. There is chunk option `cache=TRUE` but in `Sweave` it looks like there is not such solution. 
Maybe someone heard or seen options in `Sweave` that enables caching?
Thanks for help.

Comment: CRAN: [cacheSweave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/index.html)

Comment: There is a special package for that? Why people Just don't use knitr or rmarkdown? Thanks anyway.

Comment: `knitr`/`rmarkdown` didn't exist at this time; the oldest `cacheSweave` version on CRAN is from Sep 2006, `knitr 0.1` Jan 2012;

Comment: Yes. But I wonder why people still use Sweave.

Comment: @MarcinKosinski Cause if it ain't broke, don'f fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a special package for that. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/index.html